# Installing Scipy in Virtualenv

Tags: python, linux, scipy, virtualenv

I've tried many ways to install scipy but without successes. I use virtualenv on Linux Mate.
After the workon command I tried

```
pip install scipy
```

or

```
easy_install scipy
```

end every time is a "failed with exit status 1"

I tried also

```
apt-get install python-scipy
```

and I've no errors but if I run python

```
python
import scipy
```

I'll have "ImportError: No module named scipy"
What is wrong?

Comment: You could use [Anaconda](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs). It comes with Scipy.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using Miniconda to install scipy.

```
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b
```

Then, create a Conda environment with scipy installed:

```
conda create -n scipy scipy
```

Now you'll have access to the `activate` and `deactivate` scripts, used to open and close Conda environments.

```
$ source activate scipy
discarding /Users/username/miniconda/bin from PATH
prepending /Users/username/miniconda/envs/scipy/bin to PATH
(scipy)$ python
Python 2.7.11 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:57:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.version.version
'0.16.0'
```

---

[Edit] You indicated you want to use the system installed `scipy` package, that you have successfully installed via apt, in a virtualenv. You can instruct `virtualenv` to create a new environment that includes all the system Python packages like this:

```
$ virtualenv --system-site-packages scipy_env
New python executable in scipy_env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
$ source scipy_env/bin/activate
(scipy_env)$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
```

Comment: Do I have any change with virtualenv?

Comment: Conda will exist side-by-side with virtualenv. You can also use pip inside the Conda environment, if you want. It just allows you to install binaries, rather than dealing with compiling through pip (your first problem), or out-of-date apt packages (possibly the cause of your second problem).

Comment: If I deactivate my environment and digit pip install scipy, I'll read "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages". Could I link this to my virtual environment?

Comment: That existing scipy is the result of `apt-get install python-scipy`. It's possible  to link that to a virtualenv, but I think it would be easier to `pip freeze` your existing environment, and install those packages in the Conda environment with scipy.

Comment: The edit part is similar to what I want. My virtual environment calls webpy. Is it possible to have something like:  `workon webpy` ... `python`...`import scipy`

Comment: [I put scipy and web.py in a Conda environment, see the gist here.](https://gist.github.com/branning/423eb2bd93d6348a85dd) Copy that file somewhere as `environment.yml`, then in that directory call `conda env create`, and you'll be done.

Comment: Is it possible something similar to `pip install matplotlib==1.4.3` in Anaconda?

Comment: sure, you can install a specific version like that, `conda install matplotlib=1.4.3`. Conda has a SAT solver to find compatible packages. See here for translation between virtualenv and conda commands](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/_downloads/conda-pip-virtualenv-translator.html). Many are the same.